# Variable area manometer duct

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, pressure

How does one measure the pressure at the end of the manometer tube when the manometer tube itself is having a variable area?

[image: manometer with variable area tube]

Comment: Why do you think the area at the end of the manometer tube is a factor in the pressure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The area of the manometer tube makes no difference. All that matters is the difference in the heights of the two ends (labelled $x$ in your diagram). That's why pressure units like the [torr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torr) exist that are (or rather were) defined as the pressure difference when the difference in height of a mercury manometer is 1mm. All that matters is the height difference.

Comment: very good! That answers my question about using a different diameter tubing from the one the fella uses [here](http://www.leapsecond.com/pages/manometer/) in his homemade water manometer. I have a much thinner tubing used for a fishtank air pump and was hoping to rig up something similar to him. I thought I recalled the area didn't matter and @Haridev V's question clarified this all even further.